# While True vs While False

Tags: python

I understand that the following is an infinite loop (until you break out of it):

```
while True:
```

So then, what would be the need to ever use the following:

```
while False:
```

Or:

```
while not True:
```

Since the while loop only executes the code below if the while (condition):
evaluates to the boolean True, is it correct to assume that the "code" show below would never execute?:

```
while False:
    code
```

Comment: There is *no use* in a `while` loop with a hardcoded `False` result.

Comment: You could use `while False:` during development to temporarily eliminate a block of code. I find it easier to just comment it out.

Comment: If this is used, then it is 'nice' to precede the area with a comment indicating why it is blocked.  (ie "Code blocked to try something else instead, leave here so the compiler checks the code - or remove completely when ready")

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`while` only executes the loop body if the expression evaluates to a [true value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

As such, hardcoding the expression to `False` (or anything that always produces `False` or other false value), has no use other than to ensure the loop block is not executed.

Comment: Which can be useful when testing blocks of code...Use while (false) to block some code while you try another....Its a bit better than commenting the code out as the compiler will still verify the code (If that 'feature' is helpful...It depends on the coder, team, etc)